# posting pickle dumps string with urllib

Tags: python, django, encoding, pickle, urllib

I need to post data to a Django server. I'd like to use pickle. (There're no security requirements -> small intranet app.)

First, I pickle the data on the client and sending it with urllib2

```
def dispatch(self, func_name, *args, **kwargs):
    dispatch_url = urljoin(self.base_url, "api/dispatch")
    pickled_args = cPickle.dumps(args, 2)
    pickled_kwargs = cPickle.dumps(kwargs, 2)
    data = urllib.urlencode({'func_name' : func_name,
                             'args' : pickled_args,
                             'kwargs': pickled_kwargs})
    resp = self.opener.open(dispatch_url, data)
```

Recieving the data at the server works, too:

```
def dispatch(request):
    func_name = request.POST["func_name"]
    pickled_args = request.POST["args"]
    pickled_kwargs = request.POST["kwargs"]
```

But unpickling raises an error:

```
cPickle.loads(pickled_args)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <fragment>
TypeError: must be string, not unicode
```

Obviously the `urllib.urlencode` has created a unicode string. But how can I convert it back to be able to unpickling (laods) again?

By the way, using pickle format 0 (ascii) works. I can convert to string before unpickling, but I'd rather use format 2.

Also, recommendations about how to get binary data to a Django view are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

> Obviously the urllib.urlencode has created a unicode string.

`urllib.urlencode` doesn't return Unicode string.
It might be a feature of the web framework you use that `request.POST` contains Unicode strings.

Don't use `pickle` to communicate between services it is not secure, brittle, not portable, hard to debug and it makes your components too coupled.

Comment: Thanks, I see. Now, if I use JSON, how would you send the data? Is it preferable to send one JSON with one POST mapping? Or, as I did in the example, use several mappings within the POST request.

Comment: @Knack: From your example I assume that you need an RPC library e.g., RPC4Django instead of inventing your own. Or you could rethink your system to be more [RESTfull](http://tomayko.com/writings/rest-to-my-wife) to get rid of RPC semantics if you don't actually need it.